# Saving the data from plotly graph into csv or excel file

Tags: javascript, python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a pandas dataframe with 1 datetime column `date`, 2 category type columns `cat_1` and `cat_2`, and a count column `ct`. Each number in the `ct` column corresponds to count of items that fall into corresponding values of both `cat_1 & cat_2` columns generated on that particular `date`. Using plotly-Dash, I was able to create a webpage on local system where I can chose multiple combinations of `cat_1` and `cat_2` and able to view `date` v/s `count_for_chosen_combo`
plot, where `count_for_chosen_combo` is the items generated for chosen combination of `cat_1` and `cat_2` on that particular `date`. Now I want to know if I can download the data for the chosen combination for which is represented bye the  plot into csv or xlsx or any other formats with the click of mouse rather than doing it manually?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is:

1. Callback that accepts the click event of download link/button. As an Input argument here you can accept all the filters. ie. dropdown list value

```
@app.callback(Output('my-link', 'href'), [Input('my-dropdown', 'value')])
def update_link(value):
    return '/dash/urlToDownload?value={}'.format(value)
```

2. A flask route that will create a dataframe and sends it to machine using `flask.send_file`

```py
@app.server.route('/dash/urlToDownload') 
def download_csv():
    value = flask.request.args.get('value')
    # use value to perform filter on your df
    # now send the df using `send_file`.
    return send_file(your_df,
                     mimetype='text/csv',
                     attachment_filename='downloadFile.csv',
                     as_attachment=True)
```